# Why is relative path .. under a symlinked directory defined differently with different commands?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I encountered a different idea of a `..` directory in zsh than I used to know in bash.  When I use `..` **under** a symbolically linked directory, it resolves to the parent of the link instead of the parent of the current directory indicated by `$(pwd)`.

For example,

```
tmp % mkdir a b
tmp % mkdir a/c
tmp % touch a/IN_A
tmp % touch b/IN_B
tmp % cd b
b % ln -s ../a/c
b % ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 ccyang  staff  0 Apr  8 17:09 IN_B
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ccyang  staff  6 Apr  8 17:09 c -> ../a/c
b % cd c
c % ls ..
IN_A c
c % pwd
/Users/ccyang/tmp/b/c
```

Is there anything other than `..` that I can use to resolve to the current directory under a symbolic link?

EDIT #1 (2021-04-10)

Following the comments up to this point, I demonstrate further here why I get confused by this behavior.

```
c % pwd
/Users/ccyang/tmp/b/c
c % ls -l ..
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 ccyang  staff   0 Apr  8 17:09 IN_A
drwxr-xr-x  2 ccyang  staff  64 Apr  8 17:09 c
c % cd ..
b % pwd
/Users/ccyang/tmp/b
b % ls
IN_B c
```

As shown, `..` has different meanings when used with `cd` and `ls`.  I feel this inconsistency should not exist.  Could anyone explain why it is like this?

Comment: `ls ${PWD:h}` should work as a replacement for `ls ..` in your specific example, but it may not be a general-purpose solution.

Comment: @C.-C.Yang : I can not see any difference in by bash vs. zsh: In both cases, after doing a `cd` which is a symlink to a different directory,  `..` resolves to the parent of that directory. bash _4.4.12(3)-release_  and zsh _5.8_. I don't think that the **shell** is doing any resolution expliictly.

Comment: @user1934428: Thanks for checking.  I am using macOS Big Sur 11.2.3 with zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0).  So do you think it is a symptom of the OS instead of the shell?  BTW, it makes sense if **both** ``pwd`` and ``..`` show the _same_ parent, but in my example, it was not.  What did you see with ``pwd`` under a symlinked directory?

Comment: OK.  I can confirm the same behavior occurs in bash with GNU/Linux.  Somehow I got the impression that it was not like this before at some point.  I guess I need to wrap my head around and try to get used to this...

Comment: I am editing my question to explain further why it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I use `readlink -f .`. You can use `ls -L ..` i think for same meaning. But my answer as to _why_, is "why not?"?

Comment: @KamilCuk: It all boils down to my expectation.  If ```..``` means different things when used with two different commands, how could I know I am thinking of a relative path correctly when using any command?

Comment: `how could I know I am thinking` Read the documentation or the source code of the tool you want to use.